# Change a particular string in url using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to change my url from

```
http://intervideo.2watt.net/component/content/article.html?id=65&Itemid=479
```

to

```
http://intervideo.2watt.net/component/content/article.html?id=65&Itemid=332
```

I have tried the following code but it is not working

```
RewriteRule ^/?Itemid=479/(.*)$ Itemid=332/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot capture query string from `RewriteRule`. Use a `RewriteCond` instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(id=\d+)&Itemid=479$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^component/content/article\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&Itemid=332 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ::)